# Google restore after reflash to fix bootloop ends in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, restore

I have an S3 Duo+ (s3ve3g) running CM12.1. Phone suddenly went into a boot loop, could boot into safe mode ok but not main. Cleared the dalvik and let it rebuild with same result.

Booted into recovery, did a TWRP backup then cleared data, cache, system, dalvik and installed the CM ROM plus GAPPS. Booted ok, logged into google and let it download its recovery. And we're back in the bootloop.

Does this suggest that the bootloop is being caused by a recently updated program, or does Google restore settings and/or data that could cause this?

Any suggestions on how best to proceed would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No answers, so this is what I did: selectively restored parts of the google restore to identify the rogue application, then did a google restore of every but that.

The first part took about a week, the final restore took 2 1/2 days.

Comment: So, I take it the Google Backups do not happen in the matter of a couple of hours?